# Can I make use of MySQL's completion hash in Vim?

Tags: mysql, vim

In the mysql client, `\#` rebuilds the completion hash for autocompleting your command, while `\e` opens editor `$EDITOR` to edit your command.

Is there any way of making use of the completion hash in the invoked editor (Vim in my case)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [vim-addon-sql](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2376).  I've never used it myself, but it seems like the kind of thing that you're looking for.